# Sitecore Social Connected Module - How to test locally

Tags: xdb, social-connected

I am configuring my project to use Sitecore Social Connected in order to allow users to log in to the site using their Facebook account. A prerequisite of this is to have a Facebook App created (described [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/social_connected/setting_up_social_connected/configuring/walkthrough_configuring_social_connector_to_work_with_a_social_network)). Will this work when I am running the site on my machine e.g. under say localhost ? I assume I need to create a Facebook App with the "Site Url" set to localhost, but I'm not even sure if that would work and whether Facebook actually needs to be able to access my Sitecore instance? If so, I guess this could only be tested on an integration environment if it is publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I created Facebook app 2 years ago and at that point I got it working with `localhost:port` as *Site Url* and `localhost` as *App Domains*. If that doesn't work, you could try creating a "Test App". There is a menu on the top left corner. If that also fails, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295872/facebook-app-localhost-no-longer-works-as-app-domain/) has a discussion about using localhost for development of facebook apps.

[image: App settings]
[image: Create Test App menu]

Comment: I tried to add a port number but it seems not to be accepted by Facebook as it displayed a validation error saying it was not a correct hostname format.

Comment: If port number is not allowed, then try adding another binding (alias) to your localhost website in IIS, update etc/hosts file and use the new url in Facebook App. I found this suggestion here: https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/09/26/exploring-the-sitecore-social-connected-module-facebook/

Comment: Ok, I'm trying this but it has not changed the outcome, unfortunately. I will need to ask a different SSE question!

Comment: Sure, I hope you'll be able to get it working.